# Integrate Zoho Chatbot to Angular and appear after login

Tags: angular, zoho

I want the zoho chatbot to appear after I login on the site. 
I have this code in my index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $zoho=$zoho || {};$zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq ||
    {widgetcode:"d4c6b39bfbf717b01de5e6c794342659bec9d4c47c1287ce05a846c37084d4aabbbd2477760b48dca461c2fc738ec49d", values:{},ready:function(){}};
    var d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.id="zsiqscript";s.defer=true;
    s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget";t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);d.write("<div id=‘zsiqwidget’></div>");
</script>
```

But the chatbot icon appear even I'm not logged in.

So basically, I want it to appear after logging in.

Comment: did u got $zoho undefined error?

Comment: did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 1):

Put your code

```
var $zoho=$zoho || {};$zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq ||
    {widgetcode:"d4c6b39bfbf717b01de5e6c794342659bec9d4c47c1287ce05a846c37084d4aabbbd2477760b48dca461c2fc738ec49d", values:{},ready:function(){}};
    var d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.id="zsiqscript";s.defer=true;
    s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget";t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);d.write("<div id=‘zsiqwidget’></div>");
```

to salesiq.js and save in assets folder

in angular project
Add in your baseComponent - which is called after login

```
const url = 'assets/pathto/salesiq.js'; //your path to js file where joho code are there

export class MyAppComponent {
    loadAPI: Promise<any>;

   ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadAPI = new Promise((resolve) => {
            console.log('resolving promise...');
            this.loadScript();
        });
    }

    public loadScript() {
        console.log('preparing to load...')
        let node = document.createElement('script');
        node.src = url;
        node.type = 'text/javascript';
        node.async = true;
        node.charset = 'utf-8';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }
}
```